# Lazy Load Images With Webpack HTML CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack

I'm trying to do some lazy loading with my images. Here's my folder structure

```
/public
      assets
           images
      index.html
src
  css/style.css
  index.ts
```

My webpack config is here https://github.com/akashshyamdev/portfolio-html/tree/master/webpack

I've done some research and I've seen that `loading="lazy"` is used, but that does not support safari. We can use interesection observer, but that does not quite work with webpack(I use relative paths from HTML which are then replaced by webpack, if use the same path but injected through javascript, it does not work).

Keep in mind that this is lazy loading of images, NOT JAVASCRIPT code. I'm sure there is some way to do this, I'm open to using external libraries. Any help is appreciated, looking forward to your replies!

Comment: Intersection observer and webpack are two different things and there is no reason why they wouldn’t work with each other. Webpack bundles your build. IntersectionObserver works at runtime in the client.

Comment: @Terry, that's absolutely correct. My implementation involves taking a relative path(before webpack bundles) like `../../assets/images`, and so when it is dynamically set in run time, the image is broken.

Comment: And how does that have anything to do with intersection observer?

Comment: Webpack replaces '../../assets/images', with some kind of hash for caching etc